# python pqdict isn't working (from pqdict import * ImportError: No module named 'pqdict')

Tags: python

I tried:

from pqdict import *

but it doesn't work. I receive the error:

```
from pqdict import * ImportError: No module named 'pqdict'
```

I tried to check if it requires download and install, but it seems it doesn't *(and there is noothing for windowd 64 bit)*. What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't require installing? Of course it does, it's a third-party package.

Comment: you are right. how do I install it? I find no information on google... sorry for my ignorance I am really a newbie

Comment: Same way as any other Python library: `pip install pqdict`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows' command prompt. Then type in `pip install pqdict` and hit Enter. Then wait for it to install.
Once you done that, try that again. Probably will work since it is now installed.